# How to do login with stackoverflow in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to integrate stackoverflow login and signup like facebook or other social media in laravel ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package package:

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth

This package comes with a fresh Laravel 6.0 and built-in authentication system.

Or if you want to install a package on your own laravel app, I suggest you use Socilite package.
You can find the documentation using the link below.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/socialite

You can include the login and registration attempt via Stackexchange, using Stackexpchange's API by going to this link.
https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/providers/stack-exchange.

Comment: Thanks,
I have installed socialite and done login with facebook 
now i want to integrate login with stackoverflow

Comment: @CodDev, I have updated my answer and added the link where you can find how to integrate stackexchange login to your Laravel app.